# Quality of fit in LpSolve

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, lpsolve

I am using LPSolve for a system with approximately 40,000 variables, 100 sum-of-a1*x1 = c1 constraints and 40,000 x1 < n constraints. Normally I am getting a solution, but occasionally LPSolve doesnt reach a solution whereas running the same data through a similar linear programming system in MatLab will provide a solution. From observation of goodness of fit of the MatLab solutions to the sum-constraints it seems to me that MatLab is willing to accept a greater final error (parts in 10^-6) whereas the LPSolve solution (if it does solve) is always good to around parts in 10^-12.

I have tried the LPSolve manuals/tutorials etc but have not found a way to reduce the required quality of fit. There are a lot of variables/settings which the tutorials explain can be changed, but don' appear to explain what those changes actually mean (my background expertise is certainly *not* in linear programming). So my questions are:

Is my assumption valid - that LPSolve by default requires the solution to have a very small error and is somehow different to what Matlab's linprog does?

If so, can this requirement be relaxed - and if so how?

Comment: Perhaps [`set_obj_bound`](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/set_obj_bound.htm) and [`set_mip_gap`](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/set_mip_gap.htm) might be what you want? If you are using the [standalone lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/lp_solve.htm) program they can be set through the `-b` and `-ga`/`-gr` options.

Comment: I am not following what you are saying about the problem with `LpSolve` but I would agree that Matlabs `linprog` solver is a stronger solver than `LPSolve`.